# How to use Google Analytics enhanced link attribution with CloudFlare Google analytics app?

Tags: google-analytics, cloudflare

Is it possible to enable enhanced link attribution for Google Analytics while at the same time using the GA tracking code inserted through the CloudFlare Google analytics app?

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time, unfortunately. Our Google Analytics app will not work with some of the custom options that Google offers.

Comment: Any plans for integrating Universal Analytics?

Comment: We're going to revisit apps next year. While some of the custom options Google offers may not be easily done, we should be able to get some of the other options besides the standard way.